# How to change client ip address using php

Tags: php

How to change client ip address using php. Is it Possible to change client ip address if they visit our site. i'm trying to stream video which is not works in my country without vpn. So is there any way to play video without using vpn. Like using proxy in php. please help me with that i'm new in php. Thanks for your your time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but if it's what I think you're asking then no. PHP is a server-side language that cannot have any effect on the client.
You can change various things on the server though, but it's not recommended that a webserver can have that much control of the host OS if the server is public.

Comment: i have vps should i have to make changes there ?

Comment: If you are thinking about trying to change the users IP address with PHP, you cannot do anything of the sort. If you want to change the IP of the server with PHP, you can. But I advise against it at all costs.